# Let $f$ be non-negative bounded measurable function on a set of finite measure $E$. Assume $\int_Ef = 0$. Show that $f=0$ a.e on $E$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f$ be non-negative bounded measurable function on a set of finite measure $E$. Assume $\int_Ef = 0$. Show that $f=0$ a.e on $E$.

Define $A=\{ x \in E \mid f(x) \ne 0\}$. Now it seems that I want to show that $m(A)=0$. What I have is that $$0=\int_E f= \int_{E \setminus A} f + \int_{A} f \implies \int_{E \setminus A} f = \int_{A}f$$

but I’m stuck on how to get further. It seems that I have the integral over set where $f$ is non-zero equaling the integral over a set where $f$ is zero?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that the set $E_n = \{x \mid f(x) > \frac{1}{n}\}$ has measure 0. Conclude that $\{x | f(x)  > 0\}$ is a nullset, as finite measures are continuous from above.